# Merging nearby contours in Open CV

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I'm trying to merge the nearby contours into a single contour in Open CV. I'm trying to find a faster way of doing so. I tried one of the solutions from online but takes a lot of time when there are more number of differences.

This link will take you to the reference code : [Click here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2564/opencv-c-connect-nearby-contours-based-on-distance-between-them)

The below images are just for reference of result I need, what I'm looking for is any image that has contours more than 60-70 and combines the nearest contours.

[This image is before merging contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m4dl.png)

[This image is after merging contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8xRK.png)

Comment: Generally, the way to merge contours is to process the thresholded image using morphology to close gaps before finding contours.